# Can I retrieve the start and end indices from a sublist?

Tags: java, list, collections

I'm working with a library which uses a heterogeneous list of "slots".  There are several types of slot in this list (input, output, storage, …), each in a contiguous range.  I'd like to use [`list.subList(start, end)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) to pull each of these types into its own list for better management on my end, but I'll still need to call library methods which expect indices within the original list, so I'll need some way to produce those from my sublists.

Is it possible to extract the original `fromIndex` and `toIndex` used to create a sublist?  Or will I need to perform that bookkeeping myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with reflection. All JCF lists inherit AbstracList.sublist

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    return (this instanceof RandomAccess ?
            new RandomAccessSubList<>(this, fromIndex, toIndex) :
            new SubList<>(this, fromIndex, toIndex));
}
```

RandomAccessSublist is a subclass of SubList. And this is SubList

```
class SubList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    private final AbstractList<E> l;
    private final int offset;
    private int size;
```

so you can take your indexes from here.

Comment: Interesting; I suspected something like this was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Since `List.sublist` returns `List<T>`, you cannot retrieve the from and to indexes that were used to create the sublist. However, nothing stops you from storing these indexes yourself: you can easily write a wrapper yourself to keep the indexes, like this:

```
class SubList<T> implements List<T> {
    private final int fromIndex;
    private final int toIndex;
    private final List<T> wrapped;
    public SubList<T>(List<T> orig, int from, int to) {
        wrapped = orig.subList(from, to);
        fromIndex = from;
        toIndex = to;
    }
    public int getFromIndex() {
        return fromIndex;
    }
    public int getToIndex() {
        return toIndex;
    }
    public T get(int index) {
        return wrapped.get(index);
    }
    public int indexOf(object o) {
        return wrapped.indexOf(o);
    }
    ...
    // Implement the remaining List<T> methods here
}
```

Comment: I think I'll just use a `Map<List<Slot>, Integer>` for the starting indices rather than implement all of `List`.  :-)

Comment: @BenBlank The rest of the implementation is a list of pass-through calls to the `wrapper` (see the edit). It is 100% mechanical: a decent IDE can write most of the implementation to you.

Comment: Alternatively, you could subclass [Guava's `ForwardingList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html) and only need to implement the index tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you need start and end indices you will have to do the book keeping. May be extend ArrayList and override `subList` so that returned CustomList has start and end indices of backing list.

But you can do all the operations on `subList` like `clear()` `indexOf()` etc, you can process the subList and that will be reflected in parent list. This helps in most cases.

From Javadoc

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.
>   This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list. For example, the following idiom removes a range of elements from a list:

```
  list.subList(from, to).clear();
```

> Similar idioms may be constructed for indexOf and lastIndexOf, and all of the algorithms in the Collections class can be applied to a subList.
>   The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)